# Sprint board columns not getting resized with story cards in ADO

Tags: multiple-columns, calculated-columns, autoresize

In my sprint board the column size is not getting resized with story card size and entire board looks clumsy as cards occupies space in another column.
The width of columns has become very narrow on sprint board in ADO.

No option to try.
tried with browser settings however no use